# Set center of a drawable at a point

Tags: android, drawable, center, setbounds

In a custom view, is there a way I can set the center of a drawable at a certain point on the canvas? (I don't want to deal with figuring out rectangular bounds for the drawable...)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i just want to put a drawable on a screen and that drawable's center will be a point of my choosing. i know this can be done by setting bounds of the drawable, but i was wondering if i had to go through the trouble of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the call to draw the Bitmap, draw it at a point with it's left and top attributes set to the position minus half the image's width and height, respectively. That will center it at the point you want.

IE.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, xPos - bitmap.getWidth()/2, yPos - bitmap.getHeight()/2, new Paint());
```